# Design and analysis of Two inductor boost converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

how to decide inductance values in case of two inductor boost converter?
[image]

Comment: Do you just want the \$L_1\$ and \$L_2\$ values with the rest of parameters given beforehand? Or Do you need to design the entire converter? In either case, we need way more info mate.

Comment: L1 and L2 design is what i'm looking for.
information that i have about circuits are,
input voltage = 12V
output voltage = 450V
output power = 600W
if needed i'm okay to use transformer to further step-up the voltage in between switch and diode.

Answer (score 2):

The design in the question is two parallel boost converters feeding a common load via their respective diodes. The phasing of each switch will be 180deg apart to minimize ripple on the output but the basic equations for a single inductor still work.

Treat it like a single inductor discontinuous boost converter: -

- Output voltage (above Vin) and load determine max power given to load by switching.
- Half the max power divided by switching frequency is energy required to be stored in each inductor (to be released when switch goes open circuit).
- Choose inductor value to suit switching frequency so that at (typically) 50% duty the current has risen to a level that provides the energy to sustain max load wattage in the load.

If you are wanting to work in continuous mode then look up the equations but take account that the max energy per cycle needed to sustain power in the load is shared between the two inductors.

Comment: Is above design procedure is valid, if turn-on time of switches are overlapped. In overlapped situation current in both inductors will be increasing, which leads to storing of energy in inductor.

Comment: Energy is progressively stored in the either inductor when their respective switch (S1 or S2) shorts to ground. Energy is released from either inductor when their respective switch opens. If there is overlap it will only increase ripple voltage on output.